# Timed out waiting for device (efi partition) - Xubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu

I am struggling with my Xubuntu 22.04 installation, running Kernel `5.15.0-73-generic`.

Yesterday, I attempted to install a module called `ryzen_smu`, but I am unsure if it is related to the current problem I am facing.

After rebooting, the system enters emergency mode due to a timed-out partition, specifically the `/boot/efi` partition.

```
[Time] Timed out waiting for device /dev/nvme0n1p1.
[Depend] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/nvme0n1p1
[Depend] Dependency failed for Local File System.
[Depend] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
```

`Journal -xb` found this

```
systemd[1]: dev-nvme0n1p1.device: Job dev-nvme0n1p1.device/start timed out.
systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/nvme0n1p1.
```

After googling I thought it's a corrupt `fstab` and had a look. But I will say that the `fstab` is OK.

```
UUID=BEC6-FC19 /boot/efi     vfat     umask=0077    0    1
```

`blkid`

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="BEC6-FC19" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" ...
```

`blkid` shows the same `UUID`. So I tried to change it to `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, it is the efi partition. But the problem doesn't change.

I tried `mount -a` in `emergency-mode` with success, `/boot/efi` is there and I have access to all the data from the partition. Even `fsck` doesn't find any problems.

If I try to exit the `emergency-mode` with mounteod `/boot/efi` it starts, but without a GUI, just `tty1`. And `startxfce4` after that says

```
steven@NAS:~$:startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc: 3: exec: /usr/bin/X: not found
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I don't have ideas anymore. And sorry I have to type every line, network isn't working on the machine since that issue and I cannot paste from it.

Comment: Timeout errors on a disk at startup, but looks fine once you get in and check manually? That might suggest the disk/SSD starts up slower than expected, which in turn suggests the disk/SSD might be starting to fail. Check `smartctl -x /dev/nvme0n1` and/or `nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0`. The fact that `/usr/bin/X` is missing suggests that either your GUI was based on Wayland instead of X, or you might have another filesystem corruption issue, possibly on your root filesystem.

Comment: The system was running and rebooting a few times before this issue and / is on the same NVME, the other fact I cannot understand is that ubuntu has to boot from this partition but it was not possible to mount the partition in the boot routine?
After trying many stuff I rejected and was saving the data from / and reinstall xubuntu... After that everything runs as expected. But I'm worrying that it happens again.